# Shorten a long url for users in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do I shorten

```
 example.com/user.php?name=foo&id=20
```

to

```
example.com/foo/20
```

?

I am on a free webhost and my htaccess file has only 2 lines

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /user.php?name=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

RewriteCond checks if the requested filename is a directory or file , it will be passed unchanged and RewriteRule will be skipped.